# How to write a factorial calculator that extends to negative numbers?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program for a factorial which tries to calculate as such.
If n is the natural number, then the answer is n*(n-1)*(n-2)....1*(-1)*(-2))*(-3)...*(-10)

Here is C++ code which just doesn't go beyond printing n. It works without the if else statement.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int val=0, prod=1;
    std::cout<<"Enter the number"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>val;
    std::cout<<"The number is "<<val<<std::endl;
    while(val>=-10)
    {
        prod=prod*val;
        if (val=1)
        {

            val=val-2;
        }
        else
        {
            val=val-1;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<prod<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (val=1)
```

should be

```
if (val==1)
```

`=` for assignment and `==` for comparison.

I would expect your compiler to warn you about this very common error. If it didn't you should find out why, if it did you should pay attention.

Compiler warnings will save you loads of time in the long run.

Comment: Definitely enable compiler warnings, GCC and Clang would have caught this instantly with `-Wall -Werror`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes programming tests are about common sense, like in this one:
You say that you need to calculate:

```
n*(n-1)*...*1*(-1)*(-2)*...*(-10)
```

This is the same as (there's an even number of negatives, so it becomes positive):

```
n*(n-1)*...*1*fact(10) // fact(10)=3,628,800
```

So, I would just write the function for calculating the factorial of a number and multiply the result by 3,628,800.

Obviously, there might a catch: `fact(10)` is about three million, while on most computers, the maximum value of `int` (the basic type you're using) is about two billion, which is not even a thousand times larger than the value you need to multiply with.

So, instead of using a simple `int`, I'd suggest you to use integer types which can hold larger numbers, like `long long` or `unsigned long long`. Maybe this is the real purpose of this exercise?